# Spoofing Python operator precedence

Tags: python, operator-overloading, metaclass, magic-methods

I know that when I compare two objects `lhs == rhs` and both define `__eq__`, just `lhs.__eq__` is called unless it returns `NotImplemented` or `rhs` is a subclass of `lhs`.

However I would like to implement a class, instances of which while comparing to arbitrary objects will be given a chance to say what they want to say, regardless of implementation details of `arbitrary_object.__eq__` and regardless of position in comparison statement. It sounds awkward a bit, but I'm working on a little testing-oriented project, take a look at [`testmania.expect`](http://nailxx.github.com/testmania/expect.html) and you'll got the idea what I need this for.

My initial idea was to make my class to be a subclass of any other class using metaclass magic and `__instancecheck__`, `__subclasscheck__`. But they simply don't get called in case of simple comparison.

Does somebody has any fresh ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will suite your need, but why not test the two operation by that i mean test if : `object1 == object2` and `object2 == object1` and usually you should end up with the same value unless one of the object have overwrote the `__eq__` method so you will execute this new `__eq__` method and return the one that is true , an example is better than words :

```
def _assert_just_now(first, second):
    """A Dump function to simulate if two dates are almost equal.

    N.B: In this Dump function i will just test if the two datetime object have the
    same hour

    """ 

    from datetime import datetime
    assert isinstance(first, datetime) and isinstance(second, datetime), \
           "This function only accept datetime objects"

    return first.hour == second.hour

class Expectation(object):

     def __init__(self, assertion, first):
         self.assertion = assertion
         self.first = first

     def __eq__(self, other):
         return self.assertion(self.first, other)

def assert_equal(first, second):
   """Usage :

   >>> from datetime import datetime
   >>> t1 = datetime(year=2007, hour=1, month=3, day=12)
   >>> t2 = datetime(year=2011, hour=1, month=5, day=12)

   Without using Expectation it's False.
   >>> assert_equal(t1, t2)
   False

   Use the Expectation object.
   >>> assert_equal(t1, Expectation(_assert_just_now, t2))
   True

   Can use Expectation in the first argument too.
   >>> assert_equal(Expectation(_assert_just_now, t2), t1)
   True

   Work also in Container object.
   >>> assert_equal({'a': 1, 'b': Expectation(_assert_just_now, t2)},
   ...              {'a': 1, 'b': t1})
   True

   We change a little bit the values to make the assert equal fail.
   >>> t3 = datetime(year=2011, hour=2, month=5, day=12)
   >>> assert_equal(t1, t3)
   False

   This just to make sure that the _assert_just_now doesn't accept object 
   other than datetime:
   >>> assert_equal(t1, Expectation(_assert_just_now, "str"))
   Traceback (most recent call last):
       ...
   AssertionError: This function only accept datetime objects

   """

   return first == second or second == first

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import doctest
   doctest.testmod()
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, keeping Expectation always on left is a solution, but it breaks the habits: many people get used to write `some_assert(what_i_have, what_i_want_to_have)`. Changing this to inverse just for expectations isn't great idea imho.

Comment: @nailxx: Maybe i wasn't clear enough in my answer :) as you can see in the doctest you can pass the expectation object in the first or second argument of the function `assert_equal` and it will work, and that because i'm doing `first == second or second == first`, so you will execute first the `first.__eq__(second)` and if it's not True you will execute the `second.__eq__(first)` and if anyone of the object first or second is an expectation the `__eq__` correspondent will be runned :)

Comment: Ah, ok, you're about reimplementing `assert_equal` itself. Uff, it's odd a bit to replace standard `TestCase.assertEqual`. But maybe it is right direction after all.

Comment: @nailxx: you can subclass `TestCase` and define your `assertEqual` for that, but there is a catch in the code that i posted, because i follow the definition of an Expectation as "a wrapper that make a test pass when it should fail." because of that i use the `first == second or second == first`, so if an expectation is used in either in `first` or `second` one of the tests `first == second` or `second == first` will pass (or no) other wise with no Expectation (nothing that override the __eq__ of one of the object) the two tests will return same result, well hopefully this was helpful :)